# Remove any number and the remaining numbers can be partitioned into two subsets of equal sum; prove all numbers are equal.

Tags: linear-algebra, number-theory, real-numbers

Supposed I have a list of $n$ real numbers, where $n$ is odd. The list is constructed such that I can remove any arbitrary number from the list, and the remaining numbers can be partitioned into two equal-sized subsets with equal sums. Prove that all numbers in the list are equal.

This should be somehow related to linear algebra. A way I could think of to interpret this is that the list is essentially a $1 \times n$ row, and there exist $n$ $n \times 1$ vectors with one zero in some entry and $1$'s and $-1$'s in other entries with the entries summing to $0$, such that the product of the row and the column vector is $[0]$.

In other words, the entries/$1 \times 1$ columns in the row are linearly dependent once we remove any arbitrary entry/column. I'm not sure how this is/could be related to the proof though.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is a rather classic problem in the case where the elements are integers.  see [this](https://www.quora.com/Suppose-I-have-a-list-of-21-integers-After-deleting-any-one-integer-from-the-list-the-remaining-20-integers-can-always-be-partitioned-into-two-subsets-of-10-integers-each-with-an-equal-total-sum-How-do-you-prove-that-all-of-the-21-integers-are-equal) for instance.  Haven't thought about the real case, though perhaps the argument can be adapted.

Comment: I found this comment to be particularly insightful as a hint:  consider the parity of the numbers, and look for transformations that reduce their overall magnitude.

Comment: [here](http://www.math.cmu.edu/~lohp/docs/math/mop2012/combinatorics-black-soln.pdf) is a reference which gives the solution in the real case, more or less along the lines you started.  The proof is for $n=101$ but of course there is nothing special about that (other than that it is odd).

Comment: Thanks a lot! That solves my problem. The second link is super helpful - I guess I should went in the wrong direction and should have put the list as a column vector to be left-multiplied by a transformation matrix instead of left-multiplied by another vector. Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let $x=(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)$ be the vector of real numbers.

For each $1\le i \le n$, there exist disjoint sets $P_i,Q_i\subset \{1,2,\dots,n\}$ whose union is $\{1,2,\dots,n\}\setminus \{i\}$ such that $\sum_{j\in P_i}x_j=\sum_{j\in Q_i}x_j$. Let $M$ be the $n\times n$ matrix defined by
$$
M_{i,j}=\begin{cases}
1  & x_j\in P_i\\
-1  & x_j\in Q_i\\
0 & i=j\end{cases}
$$
Letting $\bf 1$ be the vector of all ones, then we have that
$$
Mx=0\qquad \text{and}\qquad M{\bf 1}=0
$$
If we can show that the null space of $M$ has dimension $1$, this will prove $x$ is a scalar multiple of $\bf 1$, so all weights are equal.

It suffices to prove that $M'$, the upper $(n-1)\times (n-1)$ submatrix of $M$, is invertible. Letting $J$ be the $(n-1)\times (n-1)$ matrix of all ones, and $I$ be the $(n-1)\times (n-1)$ identity, then each element of $M'$ is congruent mod $2$ to the corresponding element of $J-I$, so $\det M'\equiv \det(J-I)\pmod 2$. Considering $J-I$ as a matrix over $\mathbb F_2$, we have (noting each entry of $J^2$ is $n-1\equiv 0\pmod 2$)
$$
(J-I)^2 = J^2-2JI+I^2=I,
$$
which proves $J-I$ is invertible mod $2$, so $\det(J-I)\equiv 1\pmod 2$. This proves $\det M'\equiv 1\pmod 2$, so $\det M'$ is nonzero, as required.

Comment: I posted this answer so that any future copies of this question can be closed as a duplicate.

Comment: Should we close https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1002267/after-removing-any-part-the-rest-can-be-split-evenly-consequences as a duplicate of this one, or vice versa?

Comment: @bof I would say close this one as dupe of the old one. The important thing is that they get linked to each other.