# m distinct positive numbers can divide into n equal-sum subsets. Prove we can remove n numbers so the rest can't be divided

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, number-theory

As the subject suggests. We got $m$ distinct positive numbers that can divide into $n$ subsetswith equal sum. prove we can remove $n$ numbers so the rest can't divide into $n$ subsets with equal sum.

I am thinking this as a linear algebra problem like below, or even just reduce this problem to below problem, but I can't make any further progress. [Remove any number and the remaining numbers can be partitioned into two subsets of equal sum; prove all numbers are equal.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2920667/remove-any-number-and-the-remaining-numbers-can-be-partitioned-into-two-subsets)

Comment: When you say $n$ equal groups, do you mean that $m=dn$ for some $d \in \Bbb Z^+$?  Or do you mean $n$ groups, each of which has the same sum?

Comment: @RobertShore just made a few more edits. I meant the latter, n groups, each of which has the same sum

Comment: Note that in the linked question, the subsets have to be *of equal size* in addition to having the same sum. You probably want this condition for your problem, too.

Comment: Do you realise that you can delete your question? This is better than editing it to be -essentially- blank.

Comment: @user1729, when an answer has been posted, it's considered rude for OP to delete it (or to vandalize it via destructive editing). Better to just accept the answer (provided OP is satisfied that it answers the question as it was posted) and post a new question (but link the new question and the old one to each other).

Comment: @GerryMyerson Sorry, I didn't spot your answer! (This was in the review queue.) I of course agree completely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 10 distinct numbers 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19 can be partitioned into two subsets with equal sum ($1+13+17+19=3+5+7+9+11+15=50$), and no matter which two numbers you remove, you can partition the remaining eight numbers into two subsets with equal sum. I don't see any way to prove this, other than looking at all 45 ways of choosing two of the 10 numbers, and showing that for each of these 45 ways, there's a way to partition the remaining eight numbers into two sets with equal sum. I did this, but I'm not keen to type in all 45 cases.

It may work with the 8 numbers 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, that would require checking only 28 cases, but I haven't tried it.

Comment: you are right. let me check again with the person that gave me this problem.