# Showing a matrix has nullity $1$ by working $\bmod 2$

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, modular-arithmetic

I vaguely remember a linear algebra solution to the following problem but am having issues reconstructing the details. I wouldn't be surprised if this solution already exists somewhere on this site but I can't find it either. I am aware of other inductive solutions but am particularly interested in the linear algebra solution.

> Suppose you have $2n+1$ stones so that if you remove any one of them, the remaining stones can be divided into two groups of $n$ stones that have the same total weight. Show that all $2n+1$ stones have the same weight.

The argument went along the following lines: let $A$ be the $(2n+1) \times (2n+1)$ whose $i$th row records the two groups on removing the $i$th stone with $\pm1$ (say the $j$th entry is $+1$ if stone $j$ is in the first group, $-1$ if in the second group, and the diagonal is $0$). Since there are $n$ each of $+1$'s $-1$'s, each row sums to $0$, i.e. $AU = 0$ for $U$ the $(2n+1)$ vector of all $1$'s. The fact that each group has equal weight is equivalent to $AW = 0$ where $W$ is the $(2n+1)$-vector of weights of the stones. So it is enough to show that $A$ has nullity $1$ (or equivalently rank $2n$) since then we get that $W$ is a multiple of $U$.

As I remember, there is supposed to be an easy argument for this by working $\bmod 2$. Of course the nullity can only increase over $\mathbb{Z}/2$, so it is enough to show that $\operatorname{nullity}(A \bmod 2) = 1$. And this is supposed to follow from some observation about determinants $\bmod 2$, involving the parities of each row and column. Maybe applied to a minor of $A$ or $A + $ the all ones matrix.

Does anyone know how to conclude?

Comment: I think [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2920756/177399) or [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1021694/177399) is what you are looking for, yes?

Comment: Modulo 2 there is no distinction between $+1$ and $-1$. So the matrix becomes a lot nicer.